# Laravel 6.x Auth scaffold route 'verification.resend' not going to VerificationController@resend?

Tags: laravel

Trying to resend a verification email using the Laravel 6.x Auth scaffold, but I have trouble getting to the VerificationController@resend.

Route:list

```
POST    email/resend    verification.resend App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@resend web,auth,throttle:6,1
```

Button

```
<form action="{{route('verification.resend')}}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@lang('resend')</button>
</form>
```

But in VerificationController is no 'resend()' function. So I add one.

```
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        dd('VerificationController@resend', $request);
        // $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
    }
```

But the dd() never gets hit. Why not?

Otherwise the email verification works normally, I can register, receive the initial verification email, and clicking the button in that email, verifies the user as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a Trait. To be specific the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails` trait.

It has 3 functions and has another trait itself:

```php
use RedirectsUsers;

public function show(Request $request)

public function verify(Request $request)

public function resend(Request $request)
```

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/VerifiesEmails.php (version 6.x, stuff changed in 7.x)

Comment: Thanks. But if the verification email doesn't get sent, not does a dd() put into that trait gets triggered. I just get a blank page.

Comment: Then you're probably at the wrong function or controller. Its hard to tell what is going wrong.